# Calculating the number of elements of an underlying data structure

Tags: c++, c++11, recursion, boost, static

I read many comments on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4324763/c-can-we-have-functions-inside-functions) question that one really shouldn't use local classes for functionality like which my code provides, but I couldn't really put things into perspective and decide what better alternatives are there, if any (in terms of solving the problem locally). Some mentioned lambdas, although they also pinpointed that with recursion problems can arise if it is declared with the `auto` keyword. I would like to keep the logic inside of this method. Is it clean code or not? What do you think? (please don't mention `(int)size_t` casting; it's personal)

The algorithm itself calculates the number of elements of the underlying data structure, excluding folders (`AnyMap` instances).

```
typedef std::map<std::string, boost::any> AnyMap; 
using boost::any_cast;

class MyExtendedAnyMap
{
private:
    AnyMap data; // stores values and other AnyMaps as well that act as a folder basically

public:
    int size() const
    {
        if(data.empty())
            return 0;

        int calcedSize = 0;

        struct GoRec{
            static void go(const AnyMap& anyMap, int& calcedSize){
                for(const auto& kv : anyMap){
                    if(kv.second.type() == typeid(AnyMap)){
                        go(any_cast<const AnyMap&>(kv.second), calcedSize);
                    }
                    else{
                        calcedSize++;
                    }
                }
            }
        };

        for(const auto& kv : data){
            if(kv.second.type() == typeid(AnyMap)){
                GoRec::go(any_cast<const AnyMap&>(kv.second), calcedSize);
            }
            else{
                calcedSize++;
            }
        }

        return calcedSize;
    }

    // ...
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't want to question your authority but the new title puts the whole point of the question in the far background... (which was originally this: Using local class with static member function for recursion)

Comment: Titles on this site should specify the code's purpose only.  Specific questions are left only in the post body, and reviewers can comment on any aspect of the code.

Comment: Yes C++ does not have nested functions. **BUT** you can use a class and member functions to achieve the same affect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Don't Repeat Yourself**

Your looping code appears twice. Once in the body of `size()` and once in the body of `GoRec::size()`. You only need it once. In fact, the entire structure of `GoRec` is kind of weird and unnecessary. I also don't like how you named the function `go()`, made it `void`, and have it take a reference... Instead, let's write a free function:

```
size_t size_of(AnyMap const& data)
{
    size_t size = 0;
    for(const auto& kv : data){
        if(kv.second.type() == typeid(AnyMap)) {
            size += size_of(any_cast<const AnyMap&>(kv.second));
        }
        else{
            size++;
        }
    }        
    return size;
}
```

That way:

```
int size() const {
    return size_of(data);
}
```

And we have no repetition and no unnecessary extra case for empty map.

**Know Your Interface**

There are several different overloads for [`boost::any_cast`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/doc/html/boost/any_cast_idp45214624.html). You are using the wrong one. This is the one you want:

```
template<typename ValueType> const ValueType * any_cast(const any * operand);
```

This overload will not throw, and will return a null pointer if you're attempting to cast to the wrong type. Now, the overload you're using *will* throw if it's the wrong type - but you're explicitly checking that first. Effectively, you're re-implementing what `any_cast` is doing under the hood, which is bad.

If you used the other overload, you could let the `any` internal implementation remain private. And the code ends up looking more direct:

```
size_t size_of(AnyMap const& data)
{
    size_t size = 0;
    for(const auto& kv : data){
        if (auto submap = any_cast<AnyMap>(&kv.second)) {
            size += size_of(*submap);
        }
        else{
            size++;
        }
    }        
    return size;
}
```

Comment: Definitely cleaner. However I'm perfectly fine if any_cast throws, I only use  this class in try-catch blocks because there are many ways a data structure like this can throw (additionally all getters and setters are with variadic string arguments). 

The reference casting was already reviewed by people with great insight into c++, what is more they showed me the way how to implement it so it preserves const correctness. Although what you propose sure looks cleaner, a [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33084668/how-to-get-a-const-reference-to-data-held-by-boostany) to the said question.

Comment: @AndrewVegvari I'm not sure you understand my point. The reference casting is unnecessary - you want to check if your `any` is an `AnyMap` and, if it is, to do something with it. What I proposed is the way to do that.

Comment: @AndrewVegvari This will also preserve const correctness.

Comment: Yes, I get it now, since I only need a boolean result checking for successful cast, this is the way to go.

Comment: @AndrewVegvari Not a boolean result, a pointer to the correct type!

Comment: Yep, too much wine here sorry. However I managed to confuse you too, argument as `map` is fine if the for loop has too, `data` now hides the private member, bit dirty. Anyways thanks for your time and input.

Comment: @AndrewVegvari There's no hiding - I am intending this as a free function, not a member.

Comment: That is also true, I wish that I had a comment that is not total crap.

Comment: This is very minor, but I think we might as well do `++size` instead of `size++`.

Comment: @mrm Those are exactly identical in this context.

Comment: @Barry In general, I think they are different statements (I know you know). That is, it is up to the compiler to optimize unnecessary things away (but really, nobody cares here).

Answer (score 1):

In C++11, you can use a [type alias](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type_alias) instead of a `typedef`:

```
using AnyMap = std::map<std::string, boost::any>;
```

[They're mostly the same, but this is cleaner and has some other advantages with templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10747810/what-is-the-difference-between-typedef-and-using-in-c11).

Comment: I'm just letting you know, it wasn't me who gave -1 :D

Comment: @AndrewVegvari: I know (insufficient rep to downvote).  You can still check if this works.

Comment: I downvoted this. This answer simply isn't helpful - it doesn't address any of the numerous issues in OP's code.

Comment: @Barry: Reviews don't have to address specific issues being presented, just as long as they're accurate.

Comment: @Jamal Simply because it's accurate doesn't mean it's actually valuable. Posted my thoughts to meta.